# Sapper keep getting warning from client about 'this' keyword?

Tags: javascript, frontend, rollupjs, svelte, sapper

Keep getting this warning from the client, but not entirely sure what could be causing it. Any guidance in the right direction would be very helpful!

```
• client
The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
1: var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
                    ^
2:     var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
3:         extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
1: var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
                            ^
2:     var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
3:         extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
1: var __assign = (this && this.__assign) || function () {
                   ^
2:     __assign = Object.assign || function(t) {
3:         for (var s, i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
1: var __assign = (this && this.__assign) || function () {
                           ^
2:     __assign = Object.assign || function(t) {
3:         for (var s, i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
```

Comment: It looks like they are scanning a transpiled bundle, not an ES module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by adding the following code to my client rollup bundle.

`context: "window"`

Here is the documentation related to this error:
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-this-is-undefined